# Capistrano + RVM rvm_install_ruby with Rubinius

Tags: rvm, rubinius, rvm-capistrano

I am trying to fully automate the setup of my deployment host, and so avoiding manual install of Ruby.

I am using `capistrano-rvm` as it promises to do the job, but I have a problem when RVM compiles Rubinius:

```
 ** [out] rbx-2.0.0pre - #configuring
 ** [out] rbx-2.0.0pre - #compiling
*** [err] Error running '/home/app/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-1.8.7-p358/rake install', please read /home/app/.rvm/log/rbx-2.0.0pre/rake.log
```

The content of `/home/app/.rvm/log/rbx-2.0.0pre/rake.log` is:

```
ERROR: Gem rake is not installed, run `gem install rake` first.
```

How could I? That should have been done by RVM, no?

Does anyone already met & get out of this issue?

**EDIT**

I forgot to mention that RVM did load & compile `1.8.7` before `rbx`, seems like a dependence for build. Maybe RVM is running in a gem set which is badly initialized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought the 2.0.0pre was removed from rbx already, it looks like you have older RVM installation, make sure you update RVM:

```
curl -L get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --auto
rvm reload
```

This will run the installer which also makes update.

To make sure everything works properly use `rbx-2.0.testing` which is supposed to work version of rbx.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this reply. I changed the version to `rbi-2.0.testing` but still have the same problem: `ERROR: Gem rake is not installed, run `gem install rake` first.`

I am also using the `before 'deploy:setup', 'rvm:install_rvm'` directive from `capistrano-rvm`, which retrieves RVM from `https://raw.github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/master/binscripts/rvm-installer`. Does it make a difference with `get.rvm.io`? _(I get `1.12.3`)_

Comment: It know works... Was my great fault: I didn't had `zlib-dev` installed on host. :-/